# Сдвиг элеманта на 7 влево C#

Tags: c#, массивы, матрицы

Разрабатываю алгоритм. 
Не могу понять, как реализовтаь сдвиг элементов.
На вход поступаем:
string encod = "10110101010111000011110101001010101101";
Мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз в строчке бралось по 7 цифр и проходило по матрице, у меня это не получается.
Конкретно нужно в это коде

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                encoded[i] += ((data[j]) * (gmatrix[j, i]));
            encoded[i] = encoded[i] % 2;
            Console.Write("{0} |", encoded[i]);
        }
```

Пробывал вот так, но ничего не вышло

```
 for (int b = 0; b < data.Length; b+=4)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                encoded[i] += ((data[j+b]) * (gmatrix[j, i]));
            encoded[i] = encoded[i] % 2;
            Console.Write("{0} |", encoded[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Вот весь код

```
string encod = "10110101010111000011110101001010101101";
char[] data = encod.ToCharArray();
    int[] encoded = new int[11];



    char[,] gmatrix = new char[7, 11] { { '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','0','1','1','1' },
                                        { '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','1','0','1','1'}, 
                                        { '0', '0', '1', '0', '0','0', '0','1','1','0','1' }, 
                                        { '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0','1','1','1','0' },
                                        { '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0','0','0','1','1' },
                                        { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0','1','1','0','0' },
                                        { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1','1','1','1','1' },};
    int i, j;
    Console.Write("\nHamming code----- Encoding\n\nEnter 4 bit data : \n");
    Console.Write("\nGenerator matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} \t|", gmatrix[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nEncoded data ");

        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                encoded[i] += ((data[j]) * (gmatrix[j, i]));
            encoded[i] = encoded[i] % 2;
            Console.Write("{0} |", encoded[i]);
        }
                Console.ReadKey();
```